# control which replicaset is scaled up during HPA scaling in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, hpa

I have a deployment that is configured with HPA and rolling update. One of my rollouts pushed a bad change to this deployment, which triggered the creation of a new replicaset. This new replicaset tried to scale up but none of the pods became ready, so the old replicaset still hung around and I had the ready pods from the old replicaset.

So far, all is as expected.

However, this deployment received a lot of traffic and needed to scale up from 1 replica to 4. The old replicaset (good) got 1 replica and the new replicaset (bad) got 2 replicas, none of which could come up. So the deployment only ended up with 2 replicas and a loss of availability.

**How does an HPA scale pick which replicaset to increase replicas for?** If we had a way to control this we could have prevented service errors.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#how-does-a-horizontalpodautoscaler-work), I think you can use the [`spec.selector`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#how-does-a-horizontalpodautoscaler-work:%7E:text=the%20target%20resource%27s-,.spec.selector,-labels%2C%20and%20obtains) on your HPA YAML file to target specific pods to autoscale based on the details in `scaleTargetRef`. You can look sample YAML below:

```
---
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: my-hpa
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    kind: Deployment
    name: my-deployment
  targetAverageUtilization: 80
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
```

It is important to note that HPA is based on "**demand**" horizontal scaling, thus increased workload means more pods to be deployed.

Also, HPA doesn't affect objects that cannot be scaled such as Daemonset.